# TikZ-Feynman problem antiparticles

Tags: errors, tikz-feynman

The arrows of my diagram are wrong and I cant change that.

This code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [vertical=b to a] {
    i1 [particle=\(\textup{e}^{-}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2 [particle=\(\textup{e}^{-}\)],
    a -- [photon,edge label'=\(\gamma\)] b,
    f1 [particle=\(\textup{e}^{-}\)] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 [particle=\(\textup{e}^{-}\)],
};
\end{document}
```

results on this:

[image: Wrong Diagram]

And this code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram[vertical=a to b] {
    i1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] f1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)],
    a -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] b,
    i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 [particle=\(e^{-}\)],
};
\end{document}
```

results on this other diagram

[image: wrong diagram 2]

The code should result on this diagram

[image: desired one]

, however for a unkwon reason, the bottom arrows of my diagrams are reversed, as if they were antiparticles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding two anti (fermion) you get your result with `tikz-feymann` compilating with `LuaLaTeX` engine.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[vertical=a to b] {
    i1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] f1 [particle=\(e^{-}\)],
    a -- [photon, edge label=\(\gamma\)] b,
    i2 [particle=\(e^{+}\)] -- [anti fermion] b -- [anti fermion] f2 [particle=\(e^{-}\)],
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sebastiano :)

Comment: @GabrielVian You're welcome :-) and welcome in this excellent community.